# Transition to UIDocumentInteractionController takes over navigation bar title color

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Just doing a simple transition a UIDocumentInteractionController to display a PDF.  Its title is black, which is desired, but I want it to go back to the app color (white) when it goes back.  Trying to force a change in viewWillAppear does nothing (though I do see viewWillAppear is being called).  I also tried changing the color in documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview but again nothing happens.  The color stays black.
Using the following to change the color:

```
let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = textAttributes
```

Giving the UIDocumentInteractionController the navigation controller:

```
open func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        guard let vc = self.navigationController else {
            fatalError("No navigation controller")
        }
        return vc
}
```

How can i have a black title when presenting the document and white (or whatever color I desire) when i go back?  This should be something simple but ive been going in circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
```

Calling this in viewDidLoad fixed the problem